# Div under div in parent div taking 10% height in display?

Tags: html, css, height, width

I want to use one big parent div on left side to make simple menu. Then i want to give 10% height to each div (10 links) so it will make 100%. But it didn't display as 10%. How to make really shows like 10%, not as space that is enough for my content, but that 10%? Please for solution in .

Comment: please include code of what you've tried and what isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to combine this sidebar into a list element like so:

```
<div id="sidebar_wrapper">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://yourlink.com">Link #1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://yourlink.com">Link #2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://yourlink.com">Link #3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then using CSS add the height to your #sidebar_wrapper

```
#sidebar_wrapper {
width: auto;
height: 650px /* Add height you want and the link element will take 10% of this*/;
}

#sidebar_wrapper ul li a {
width: 100%;
height: 10% /* Link will take 10% times the amount of links inside that it takes to fill the height of the #sidebar_wrapper */;
}
```

Then customize the CSS as required! Keep in mind every screen resolution is different and 10% of one screen will be different compared to someone else, unless you have a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple, strange you did not tried anything...

http://jsbin.com/pejame/1/edit?html,css,output

```
<div id="menu">
  <div>...</div> <!-- x10 -->
</div>
```

page content here

```
#menu{ /* fixed left menu */
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
  width:10%;
}
#menu > div{
  height:10%;
}
#page{ /* scrollable page contents */
  margin-left:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why to limit your menu height and your links number? every addition link you will need to update the percentage. another thing is the vertical space inside the link because of the height, you can do it better without the height, but here is your example:

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#">link 1</a>
    <a href="#">link 2</a>
    <a href="#">link 3</a>
    <a href="#">link 4</a>
    <a href="#">link 5</a>
    <a href="#">link 6</a>
    <a href="#">link 7</a>
    <a href="#">link 8</a>
    <a href="#">link 9</a>
    <a href="#">link 10</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*
{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu
{
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

.menu a
{
    display: block;
    height: 10%;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 5%;
    background: #eee;
    color: #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n42pqwnt/

Answer (score 0):

see http://jsfiddle.net/alemarch/e2pndkvj/ for detail

```
#bigParent{
   height: 100%; 
   position:fixed;  /*depend of the rest of the page*/
}

.divChild {
    margin: 0px;
    height: 10%;
}


html, body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
```